# What does a "errorType": "string" mean in AWS Lambda?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am currently trying to test out a lambda function using the cognito-sync-trigger blueprint. I have added my own function code with no errors however when I test it I get ***Execution result: failed***

This is the results from the log details

```
{
  "errorType": "string",
  "errorMessage": "{\"datasetName\":\"googleUserData\",\"eventType\":\"SyncTrigger\",\"region\":\"us-east-1\",\"identityId\":\"us-east-1:1a8870db-2510-4c42-a1d5-6e895bb52040\",\"datasetRecords\":{\"name\":{\"newValue\":\"amishra2\",\"oldValue\":\"amishra\",\"op\":\"replace\"},\"email\":{\"newValue\":\"amishra2@asmtechnology.com\",\"oldValue\":\"amishra@asmtechnology.com\",\"op\":\"replace\"}},\"identityPoolId\":\"us-east-1:3a7a90d7-b0e7-4730-b0aa-866c9a16ec85\",\"version\":2}",
  "trace": []
}
```

Log output

```
aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:34:10)
        at Request.VALIDATE_PARAMETERS (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:126:42)
        at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20) {
      message: "Unexpected key '8' found in params.Item['email_address']",
      code: 'UnexpectedParameter',
      time: 2020-04-18T20:37:52.408Z
    },
    UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key '9' found in params.Item['email_address']
        at ParamValidator.fail (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:50:37)
        at ParamValidator.validateStructure (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:77:14)
        at ParamValidator.validateMember (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:88:21)
        at ParamValidator.validateMap (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:117:14)
        at ParamValidator.validateMember (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:92:21)
        at ParamValidator.validateStructure (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:75:14)
        at ParamValidator.validateMember (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:88:21)
        at ParamValidator.validate (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:34:10)
        at Request.VALIDATE_PARAMETERS (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:126:42)
        at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20) {
      message: "Unexpected key '9' found in params.Item['email_address']",
      code: 'UnexpectedParameter',
      time: 2020-04-18T20:37:52.408Z
    },
    UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key '10' found in params.Item['email_address']
        at ParamValidator.fail (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:50:37)
        at ParamValidator.validateStructure (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:77:14)
        at ParamValidator.validateMember (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:88:21)
        at ParamValidator.validateMap (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:117:14)
        at ParamValidator.validateMember (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:92:21)
        at ParamValidator.validateStructure (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:75:14)
        at ParamValidator.validateMember (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:88:21)
        at ParamValidator.validate (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:34:10)
        at Request.VALIDATE_PARAMETERS (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:126:42)
        at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20) {
      message: "Unexpected key '10' found in params.Item['email_address']",
      code: 'UnexpectedParameter',
      time: 2020-04-18T20:37:52.408Z
    },
    UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key '11' found in params.Item['email_address']
        at ParamValidator.fail (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:50:37)
        at ParamValidator.validateStructure (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:77:14)
        at ParamValidator.validateMember (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:88:21)
        at ParamValidator.validateMap (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:117:14)
        at ParamValidator.validateMember (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:92:21)
        at ParamValidator.validateStructure (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:75:14)
        at ParamValidator.validateMember (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:88:21)
        at ParamValidator.validate (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validatorEND RequestId: cf0d5cfd-29a0-434d-817b-93bf4328961a
REPORT RequestId: cf0d5cfd-29a0-434d-817b-93bf4328961a  Duration: 346.12 ms Billed Duration: 400 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 82 MB  Init Duration: 362.75 ms
```

My code for the lambda func is as follows.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

AWS.config.update({region: 'us-east-1'});


    exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {

        if (event.eventType !=='syncTrigger'){

            callback(JSON.stringify(event));
        }
        if (!(('name' in event.datasetRecords) && ('email' in event.datasetRecords))){
            callback(JSON.stringify(event));
        }
        var name = event.datasetRecords.name.newValue;
        var email = event.datasetRecords.email.newValue;

        var shouldDeleteRecord = (event.datasetRecords.name.op === 'remove') || (event.datasetRecords.email.op === 'remove');

        if (shouldDeleteRecord === true) {
            // do not delete from dynamo DB
            callback(null, event);
        }
       // var db = new doc.DynamoDB();
        var db = new AWS.DynamoDB({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});
        var params = {'TableName' : 'User', 
    'Item': {'id' : event.identityId, 'username' : name, 'email_address': email}};

        db.putItem(params,function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('User insert failure', err);
                callback(err);
            } else {
                console.log('User insert success', data);
                callback(null, event);
            }
        });
    }
```

Here is the test event code

```
{
  "datasetName": "googleUserData",
  "eventType": "SyncTrigger",
  "region": "us-east-1",
  "identityId": "us-east-1:1a8870db-2510-4c42-a1d5-6e895bb52040",
  "datasetRecords": {
    "name": {
      "newValue": "amishra2",
      "oldValue": "amishra",
      "op": "replace"
    },
    "email": {
      "newValue": "amishra2@asmtechnology.com",
      "oldValue": "amishra@asmtechnology.com",
      "op": "replace"
    }
  },
  "identityPoolId": "us-east-1:3a7a90d7-b0e7-4730-b0aa-866c9a16ec85",
  "version": 2
}
```

If anyone could steer me in the right direction as to why I am getting this error it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a Node user, but it appears from the [AWS Node SDK documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#putItem-property) that you need to **specify the type** of the parameters being added, like this:

```js
var params = {
  Item: {
   "AlbumTitle": {
     S: "Somewhat Famous"
    }, 
   "Artist": {
     S: "No One You Know"
    }, 
   "SongTitle": {
     S: "Call Me Today"
    }
  }, 
  ReturnConsumedCapacity: "TOTAL", 
  TableName: "Music"
 };
```

Your code does not seem to have the `S:` bits:

```
var params = {
  'TableName' : 'User', 
  'Item': {
    'id' : event.identityId,
    'username' : name,
    'email_address': email
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DynamoDB DocumentClient` instance instead of `DynamoDB` instance, the you no need define type of each attribute.

Replace

```
var db = new AWS.DynamoDB({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});
```

with

```
var db = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this in my case its worked.

callback(null,event);

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).